# How to format a cell in matrix control in RDLC report?

Tags: sql-server-2005, rdlc

I am getting a value from stored procedure (ex:the value  is 84.56). In RDLC file I have choose  P2 format for that cell . (it will show like 84.56%)

But I have to show like 85%.(ex:if the value is 84.32 then 84%).

How can I do this? Which format should I apply to the cell?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score -1):

Im having trouble to do this my self as well in a tablix,  but I found this code, I think it may help

> =iif(Fields!field.Value >= 85 , "PaleGreen", "White")

Put that in the color dialog, in the fx section.

hope it helps